# DataRow - OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32

Tags: c#, exception, overflow, datarow

### Issue

I have come across some existing code that throws the error below, this is using .net framework 4.5.2 and v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll

I have simplified the code example down to the part throwing the error.

Had a look at the decompiled dll and it seems to be a bug there and also looked for a new version that fixes this bug but it seems this is the latest version of System.Data.

The DB datatype is bigint

How would I go about updating the row data in a way that respects the int64 value that is being passed in and to not have it try to covert to int32?

### Error

```cs
    Exception whilst flushing buffered appenders: System.ArgumentException:Value 
    was either too large or too small for an Int32.Couldn't store 
    <32370073298665472> in SerialisationTimeMilliseconds Column.  Expected type 
    is 
    Int32. ---> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too 
    small 
    for an Int32.
       at System.Convert.ToInt32(Int64 value)
       at System.Int64.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
       at System.Data.Common.Int32Storage.Set(Int32 record, Object value)
       at System.Data.DataColumn.set_Item(Int32 record, Object value)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Data.DataColumn.set_Item(Int32 record, Object value)
       at System.Data.DataRow.set_Item(DataColumn column, Object value)
```

### Code

```cs
    private static void PopulateRow(long number, DataRow row)
    {
         row[0] = number;
    }
```

Comment: well.... what is the defined column type of the first column? i.e. what is `row.Table.Columns[0].DataType` ? I suspect it is `Int32`

Comment: tested locally with the first column defined as `int` and then `long` - as `int`, it fails in **exactly** the way described; as `long`, it works perfectly. So... check how the column is defined?

Comment: updated - the db column is bigint

Comment: ah, the column definition in the code was obfuscated, I had assumed it picked up the datatype of the value being passed in. Fixed it

Comment: no, not the DB column type; the type **defined in the `DataTable`**. When you create a datatable, you can specify the types of each column in the `DataTable`. If you get it wrong, bad things happen (like here). So: when you create this `DataTable`, how are you configuring the columns and their types? (as a side note: the number of times you should typically be using `DataTable` is very low... not quite zero, but: very low)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

column definition in the code was obfuscated, I had assumed it picked up the datatype of the value being passed in.

Changed from

```cs
    Columns.Add("number", typeof(int));
```

to

```
    Columns.Add("number", typeof(long));
```